# If statement not working. working with Dates

Tags: python-3.x, date

Good afternoon,

I am trying to work on a code that reads a date/time value and checks if the it is older than 2, 4, 7 days. Preferably I would like to consider business days only. I wrote the simple code with normal days but it seems that Python is not going though my IF statements:

```
def Calc_Date(datestring):
    a = datestring
    date_time_ticket = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    date_today = datetime.date.today()
    date_only = date_time_ticket.date()
    minus_2_days = date_today - timedelta(days=2)
    minus_4_days = date_today - timedelta(days=4)
    minus_7_days = date_today - timedelta(days=7)
    minus_14_days = date_today - timedelta(days=14)
    minus_21_days = date_today - timedelta(days=21)
    print(date_today, type(date_today))
    print(date_only, type(date_only))
    print(minus_2_days, type(minus_2_days))
    if date_only < minus_2_days:
        print('lower than 2')
    elif date_only < minus_4_days:
        print('lower than 4')
    elif date_only < minus_7_days:
        print('lower than 7')
```

this is the result I get:

```
2021-06-03 <class 'datetime.date'>
2021-06-01 <class 'datetime.date'>
2021-06-01 <class 'datetime.date'>
```

Calc_Date('01-Jun-2021 16:18:59')

Comment: What do you expect? date_only and minus_2_days are the same date (2nd and third line you print). When debugginh, add also the `else` condition. and print <, ==, >. And also the difference. It helps

Comment: `minus_2_days` is `06-01`. `minus_4_days` is `05-30`. `minus_4_days` is `05-27`. `date_only` which is `06-01` is not less than any of those.